# Does Authorize.Net have form posting like PayPal Standard?

Tags: paypal, authorize.net

We have a simple HTML site without any server code.

It is currently using ***PayPal Standard*** to sell few items (less than 10). However, we would like to switch to Authorize.Net, because we are already using Authorize.Net for other ASP.Net projects.

Is there any payment method in Authorize.Net which accepts a posted form from simple HTML page (without any server code)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Direct Payment Method](http://developer.authorize.net/api/dpm/) does what you're looking for.